# Accidentally stop the tmux job via remote shell

Tags: ssh, tmux

I usually connect to `host` using the following command:

```
ssh -t user@host tmux
```

then

```
ssh -t user@host tmux a
```

after a disconnect/logout.

I like to use a plethora of opportunities provided by `tmux`. One of them is <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> to zoom-in and zoom-out one of the panes. Pressing the combination of keys without delay (w/o releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) leads to stopping of the `tmux` without possibility to turn it back to the foreground, as there is no command line prompt to type `fg` command.

Only way to solve the problem I found is to press <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. `ssh` handles this combination of the keys and disconnects from the remote host. Then I have to connect to remote host again.

How to make remote login shell (e.g. `bash` as opposite to *remote shell* `ssh`) to handle that combination of keys?

Comment: Using child shell `ssh -t user@host "bash -c 'tmux a'"` not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> runs the `suspend-client` command in `tmux`. If this is causing you problems, perhaps you should just unbind <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> (add `unbind ^Z` to your `.tmux.conf`)?

You could bind `suspend-client` to something else if you really want, or you can just run it with the `tmux` command prompt (<kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>, followed by `suspend-client`).

Comment: How to turn back client from suspend?

Comment: Do you mean `.tmux.conf` on remote system? Can I do it via environment variables and `ssh -o SendEnv=` way?

Comment: Yes, I mean `.tmux.conf` on the remote system. If you can't access that for some reason, you could unbind as part of the initial `tmux` command, like `ssh -t user@host 'unbind ^Z ; tmux a'`.

Comment: `unbind: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, confusion. I meant `ssh -t user@host 'tmux unbind ^Z \; a'`.